# Do complex thread index calculations have an impact on the performance?

Tags: cuda

I have just asked myself if complex index calculations with e.g. threadIdx.x have an impact on the performance. Do these variables become constant as soon as the kernel is uploaded to the device?

I want to navigate to a huge array where the index depends on threadIdx.x, threadIdx.y and threadIdx.z. I need e.g. modulo operations like

```
array[threadIdx.y % 2 + ...]
```

Comment: every calculation has an impact, and there are public informations how many cycles each calculation and each read or write needs. Regarding access of built-in variables such as `threadIdx` They can be treated as constant as far as I know. If you perform duplicate calculations just save those calculations in a register or trust your compiler and check your assembly and gpu ressource usage of your kernel (In case you have enough registers so your concurrent blocks per sm do not get reduced). I prefer writing clean optimized code over trusting your compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested, I have evaluated the corresponding PTX code.

(1) Complex thread ID calculations have an impact on the performance. "threadIdx.x" etc. are not constants.

(2) "threadIdx.y % 2" is implemented efficiently and corresponds to "threadIdx.y & 0x00000001" (Cuda Toolkit 5.5).

Answer (score 3):

You have an addition and a modulus in your index computation.

From CUDA programming guide: The throughput of `operator+` is very high (160 for a 3.5 compute capable GPU).

`operator%` requires tens of operations with a throughput similar to `operator+`.

In your case you are using `operator%` with a literal constant and the compiler will very likely optimize it out. Also your constant is a power of two number (2) so the compiler will replace it with the bitwise `operator&` (same throughput as `operator+`).

It is important to profile your application to avoid wasting time optimizing arithmetic operations without gaining any performance.
It's common that arithmetic operations are completely hidden by memory load and store operations in which case you need to focus on optimizing memory throughput.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that

```
array[threadIdx.y % 2 + ...]
```

is just an example.

Generally speaking, the `%` operations can be slow. A useful trick to speed up index calculations is noting that

```
foo%n==foo&(n-1) if n is a power of 2
```

So, perhaps for the example above the compiler will make this optimization for you, but in case you have `foo%n`, the trick above is worth to be using.